# Can we remove image preview from ui fileuploader?

Tags: file-upload, magento2, admin, preview, uicomponents

Is it possible to remove image preview from UI fileuploder component, without using file component?

here is my code=>

```
 <field name="file">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">TestGroup</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">File</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
            <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/image-preview</item>
            <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
            <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="controller/index/upload"/>
            </item>
      </argument>
    </field>
```

tried by removing item name= elementTmpl and previewTmpl but not working
can anybody help me to disable the image preview for fileupload.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the src of image every time you click:

```
$("#input1").click(function () {    
    $('#imagepreview1').attr('src','');
});
```